# Starting JobIntentService from PendingIntent (Notification button)?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

In my app, I have a notification button that fires off a short network request in the background using an IntentService. It does not make sense to show a GUI here, which is why I use the service instead of an Activity. See the code below.

```
// Build the Intent used to start the NotifActionService
Intent buttonActionIntent = new Intent(this, NotifActionService.class);
buttonActionIntent.setAction(NotifActionService.ACTION_SEND_CONFIRM);
buttonActionIntent.putExtra(NotifActionService.EXTRA_CONFIRM_ID, confirmId);
buttonActionIntent.putExtra(NotifActionService.EXTRA_NOTIF_ID, notifId);

// Build the PendingIntent used to trigger the action
PendingIntent pendingIntentConfirm = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, buttonActionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This works reliably but with the new background restrictions in Android 8.0 made me want to move to a JobIntentService instead. Updating service code itself seems very straight forward but I don't know how to launch it via a PendingIntent, which is what Notification Actions require.

How could I accomplish this?

Would it be better move to a normal service and use PendingIntent.getForegroundService(...) on API levels 26+ and the current code on API level 25 and below? That would require me to manually handle wakelocks, threads and result in an ugly notification on Android 8.0+.

**EDIT: Below is the code I ended up with besides the straight forward conversion of the IntentService to a JobIntentService.**

The BroadcastReceiver which just changes the intent class to my JobIntentService and runs its enqueueWork method:

```
public class NotifiActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.setClass(context, NotifActionService.class);
        NotifActionService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Modified version of the original code:

```
// Build the Intent used to start the NotifActionReceiver
Intent buttonActionIntent = new Intent(this, NotifActionReceiver.class);
buttonActionIntent.setAction(NotifActionService.ACTION_SEND_CONFIRM);
buttonActionIntent.putExtra(NotifActionService.EXTRA_CONFIRM_ID, confirmId);
buttonActionIntent.putExtra(NotifActionService.EXTRA_NOTIF_ID, notifId);

// Build the PendingIntent used to trigger the action
PendingIntent pendingIntentConfirm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, buttonActionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> How could I accomplish this?

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` and a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`, then have the receiver call the `JobIntentService` `enqueueWork()` method from its `onReceive()` method. I'll admit that I haven't tried this, but AFAIK it should work.

Comment: Yes, that could work. I'll give it a go and mark your answer as accepted once I've made sure it does indeed solve my problem on both new and old platforms.

Comment: Did you succeed? And, if yes, could you please post an example? THX

Comment: @tomseitz I have not tried it yet as I focused on other changes instead so far. I really don't benefit much from targeting Android O at this point. It's more that I'd like to do so because I like targetting the latest version.

Are you having the same issue?

Comment: Can anyone of you please give some example, how did you achieve this. I'm trying it for my app widget.

Comment: Can I achieve something like updating my app widget everytime the screen is unlocked e.g. screen_on action?

Comment: @MuhammadMehdiRaza: "Can I achieve something like updating my app widget everytime the screen is unlocked e.g. screen_on action?" -- not on Android 8.0+, AFAIK, as `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is not listed on [the roster of implicit broadcast exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

Comment: @LoveForDroid: I am not certain what "it" is in your question, but everything in my answer should work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I was asking about your answer. Thanks for confirming!!