# Launching IntentService when tapping notification causes app to crash

Tags: android, android-notifications

The app crashes when the user taps on the a notification on android Oreo and later: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent. I understand it is because of the background service limit introduced in android Oreo. However I am not sure what options do I have since I need to launch an IntentService to do some short background job immediately after the user taps on the notification.

In FCM's onMessageReceived method:

```
    val denyIntent = Intent(this, DenyService::class.java)
    denyIntent.putExtra(VIDEO_EXTRA_SESSION_ID, sessionId)
    denyIntent.putExtra(VIDEO_DENY_REASON, "callee_action_deny")
    val denyIntentCode = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
    val pendingIntentDeny = PendingIntent.getService(this, denyIntentCode, denyIntent, 0)
    notificationBuilder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntentDeny)
    notificationBuilder.addAction(
            R.drawable.ic_call_reject,
            getString(R.string.chat_action_reject),
            pendingIntentDeny
    )



class DenyService : IntentService("DenyCall")
```

Comment: Create a foreground service

Comment: @Psypher The thing is this service is launched with a PendingIntent the client code has no control over how the service is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no differentiation when it comes to restrictions imposed for starting `Service` or `IntentService`. The restriction is applicable for starting services in background, when your application is not in foreground, hence applicable for both.

Since you are dealing with `Notification` and cannot control start of your Service you can do following:

**Approach 1**

For API level Android O and above, instead of `PendingIntent.getService`, Use [PendingIntent.getForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getForegroundService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

> this will start a foreground service, like calling
>   Context.startForegroundService()

Convert your `IntentService` to Service and immediately make it a Foreground service by displaying notification and calling `startForeground()`.

**Apporach 2:**

Based on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services):

> Under following circumstances, a background app is placed on a
>   temporary whitelist for several minutes:
>
> - Handling a high-priority Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) message.
> - Receiving a broadcast, such as an SMS/MMS message.
> - **Executing a PendingIntent from a notification.**

While an app is on the whitelist, it can launch services without limitation, and its background services are permitted to run.

Its strange in your case that you cannot run `IntentService`, could be because no visible notificaiton. You can extend a `Service` and immediately make it a Foreground service by displaying notification and calling `startForeground()`.

**Approach 3:**

Use JobIntentService. Follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139861/starting-jobintentservice-from-pendingintent-notification-button) for implementation details

Comment: The service is launched by framework code since it is a notification PendingIntent. We can't call Context.startForegroundService in app code.

Comment: An IntentService is also a Service, when it is used to handle a PendingIntent from a notification shouldn't it be in the whitelist?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on specific devices (like Samsung devices). When the user clicks an action button on a notification (which is supposed to start an intent service) - the IntentService is not started and onHandleIntent is not executed.